# Vimeo Embed Language/Subtitles

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I'm using Vimeo to host video files for a project however the videos can be in up to 8 languages. We are using subtitles PER VIDEO to split the languages up (1 video, 8 subtitle files).

The problem is I'm not able to find in the API docs or anywhere else if there's is a possibility of setting the language of the subtitles using the API or perhaps the iframe embed attributes.

Any help on this matter would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to set the language when uploading the subtitles, or viewing the video?

Comment: It's in my embed. Typically on for example a Youtube player there is a lang/locale attribute. It seems Vimeo hasn't these options.

Comment: We will be adding new JS features in the near future, but they are not ready yet. Keep an eye out!

Comment: Hey, did you figure this out? I'm trying to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Hey Emil, I actually built a custom subtitle engine in the end. It wasn't fun but Vimeo just doesn't have this possiblity. As Dashron said. If you'd like help with creating a custom subtitle engine let me know!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vimeo force CC language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27014658/vimeo-force-cc-language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To all who are curious, I ended up building my own subtitle engine. The client had the subtitle files already created so using those and some clever JS parsing found online I was able to recreate subtitle functionality on my end.

Let me know if you need help with that :)

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [Vimeo force CC language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27014658/vimeo-force-cc-language/49050324#49050324)

You can use the `enableTextTrack` function on a player initialized by the JS API provided by Vimeo:

```
// Select with the DOM API
var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
var iframePlayer = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);

player.enableTextTrack('en').then(function(track) {
    // track.language = the iso code for the language
    // track.kind = 'captions' or 'subtitles'
    // track.label = the human-readable label
}).catch(function(error) {
    switch (error.name) {
        case 'InvalidTrackLanguageError':
            // no track was available with the specified language
            break;

        case 'InvalidTrackError':
            // no track was available with the specified language and kind
            break;

        default:
            // some other error occurred
            break;
    }
});
```

More information on the github of Vimeo player JS API: https://github.com/vimeo/player.js#enabletexttracklanguage-string-kind-string-promiseobject-invalidtracklanguageerrorinvalidtrackerrorerror